# SSRS Chart visibility based on data

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008

I am currently trying to apply some conditional formatting to a report that will allow me to hide a chart when there is no data available. like [here](http://www.midnightdba.com/Jen/2012/01/ssrs-tip-hide-a-tablix-if-no-rows-returned/)

The problem I have is that several charts are built off a single data set and filters are applied within the chart properties to set the content. In some cases these filters will cause the chart to have no data (e.g. if a store doesn't stock that product line).

I have tried the method I mentioned above, however I think that because my dataset does have data for the store (just not a specific product line) it doesn't hide the chart.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you trying to filter out rows or entire tables?
 if rows, you can set a row visibility expression - like IIF(Fields!hideme.Value is nothing, true, false)
 or, alternatively, you can set a row filter under the group properties to do the same thing - select the column that is null that you want to hide when null. This is how it's going to work everywhere when setting visibility, tables/columns/rows etc.
 hope that helps

Comment: I am actually trying to hide the entire chart. In my report I have 2 instances of the chart driven from the same dataset. The first chart shows a full national picture, then the second chart has filters applied to only show data for a specific store (where the report is for them). Sometimes it will occur where the store version of the report won't result in any data as a result of the filters applied to the chart. In this circumstance I would like to hide the chart rather than having a heading for the chart and a 'no data to display' message.